# C# EF6 lazy loading does not work after exeption or after state is detached

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
switch (entry.State)
{
    case EntityState.Added:
        entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
        break;
    case EntityState.Modified:
        entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entry.OriginalValues);
        entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        break;
    case EntityState.Deleted:
        entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        break;
}
```

Whenever there is an exception this code is executed to change the state of the EF context. Problem is that after exception lazy loading does not work any more. the same is after `EntityState.Detached` is called.

Why lazy loading does not work? Can I somehow reload whole context with lazy loading or what to do?

Comment: Don't keep using a context if it has had errors. Create a new instance.

Comment: Why to create new instance? Then user will be logged out.

Comment: Because of errors. I want to remove unusd states

Comment: Yes, but why? How are you going to use this context afterwards? And why should a user get logged out if you create a new context instance?

Comment: Because then context is new and not valid any more. So your idea is just replace context. I can try.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to attach an entity explicitly after setting it to `Detached`.

```
context.Blogs.Attach(existingBlog);
```

This should enable change tracking and lazy loading.

Also

> context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled should be true.
>   context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled should be true.

See this MSDN article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx